# How to fit 3d rectangular of same size Items in box

Tags: knapsack-problem

Iam working on a project that requires me to find the quantity of items that can fit in a single box. all the items are Identical with same dimentions. I need to calculate the number if the items are stackable and/or flipable or not.
I saw alot of knapsack algorithems but all about different size items and weight. here is my code. Stack allow for stacking items if not stackable only one item can be placed in the Z axis. flip is switching between the 6 directions of the items it starts with 5 to 0 I tried to flip each time and try to place. My problem is overlapping items and the flip without stack give wrong numbers.Thanks in advanced

```
    private int Calculate(int X,int Y,int Z,int Xb,int Yb,int Zb,Boolean stack,int flip)
    {
        int result = 0;
        if ((X > Xb || Y > Yb || Z > Zb )&& flip == 0) { return 0; }

        else
        {
            int Xc=0,Xr=0,Yc=0,Yr=0,Zc=0,Zr = 0;
             Xc = Xb / X;
             Xr = Xb % X;
             Yc = Yb / Y;
             Yr = Yb % Y;
            if (stack)
            {
                 Zc = Zb / Z;
                 Zr = Zb % Z;
            }

                if (stack) {

                    result= Zc * Xc * Yc;
            }
            else {
                    //Seq.Text += "no stack";
                    result= Xc * Yc;
                }
            if (result > 0) Seq.Text += result+" flip "+flip+" ";
            if (flip == 0)
                    return result;
            else
            {

                int flip2 = --flip;
                if (flip2 == 4 || flip2 == 2 || flip2 == 0)
                { int x = Calculate(X, Z, Y, Xb, Yr, Zb, stack, flip2) + Calculate(X, Z, Y, Xr, Yb, Zb, stack, flip2) + Calculate(X, Z, Y, Xb, Yb, Zr, stack, flip2);
                        return result + x;
                }

                else if (flip2 == 3)
                { int x= Calculate(Z, X, Y, Xr, Yb, Zb, stack, flip2) + Calculate(Z, X, Y, Xb, Yr, Zb, stack, flip2) + Calculate(Z, X, Y, Xb, Yb, Zr, stack, flip2);     
                    return result + x;
                }
                else if (flip2 == 1)
                {
                    int x = Calculate(Y, Z, X, Xb, Yr, Zb, stack, flip2) + Calculate(Y, Z, X, Xb, Yb, Zr, stack, flip2) + Calculate(Y, Z, X, Xr, Yb, Zb, stack, flip2);

                    return result + x;
                }

                else return 0;



            }

        }
    }
```